# ImportError: cannot import name 'MealSerializer' from partially initialized module 'delivery_api.main.serializers'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

When I insert this line `cart = CartSerializer()` into my serializer to get detailed information, I get an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'MealSerializer' from partially initialized module 'delivery_api.main.serializers' (most likely due to a circular import)`. What is the reason for this and how to solve it?

cart/serializers.py

```
class CartMealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    meal = MealSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = CartMeal
        fields = ['id', 'meal', 'qty', 'final_price']

class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    meals = CartMealSerializer(many=True)
    owner = CustomerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = '__all__'
```

main/serializers.py

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    cart = CartSerializer() *<--- This line causes an error*

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'cart', 'phone', 'address', 'status', 'created_at']
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: Your `MealSerializer` is likely defined in the same module as the `OrderSerializer`, hence you have two serializers that refer to each other.

Comment: I moved the OrderSerializer to cart/serializers.py and it solved my problem, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You here have (likely) two files that try to import each other. This does not make sense since your `main.serializers` module aims to import the `CartSerializer` located in the `cart.serializers` module, and the `cart.serializer` module aims to import the `MealSerializer` defined in the `main.serializers`.

It also makes no sense that two serializers import each other: this would usually result in infinite recursion where the serializer of a `Meal` serializes its `Order` and that will serialize the related `Meal`s. If you would serialize it like that, that would mean you have infinite recursion, and thus would generate a file with infinite cascades, so something like `{ 'cart': { 'meals': { 'meal': { 'cart': { 'meals': { 'meal': { … } } } } } } }`.

You thus should define serializers that do not use another serializer, and use this to define a *limited* number of iterations. For example by defining a `SimpleMealSerializer` at the top of the `cart.serializers` module that does not make extra subserializations, so something like:

```
# cart/serializers.py

# no import of the MealSerializer

class SimpleMealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Meal
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'price']

class CartMealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    meal = SimpleMealSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = CartMeal
        fields = ['id', 'meal', 'qty', 'final_price']

class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    meals = CartMealSerializer(many=True)
    owner = CustomerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = '__all__'
```